# Netlogo: Set specific setxy patern with set number of turtles?

Tags: netlogo

Is it possible to create a set number of turtles, from a file, to have their own patches?  Like always be in the same location?

I've got 106 turtles I'm reading in from a file and I was hoping to have them be created on their own patches, like a square latice kind of thing.  I want to be able to look at the model world and easily identify a turtle.

```
file-open "turtledata_A.txt"
show file-read-line
while [not file-at-end?] 
[
set param read-from-string (word "[" file-read-line "]")
create-turtles 1 [setxy ??]
]
file-close 
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably easiest to use the `csv` extension and just add xy data to the file you're reading in. For example, if you have a `turtle_data.csv` file that looks like:

```
param-to-read,x,y
John,-10,10
Billy,-5,5
Bob,0,0
Simon,5,-5
Michael,10,-10
```

You can do:

```
extensions [ csv ]

turtles-own [ param ]

to setup
  ca
  reset-ticks
  file-close-all
  file-open "turtle_data.csv"

  ;; read the headings line in to skip it for data extraction
  let headings csv:from-row file-read-line

  while [ not file-at-end? ] [
    let data csv:from-row file-read-line
    create-turtles 1 [
      set param item 0 data
      setxy item 1 data item 2 data
    ]
  ]

  file-close-all
end
```

which would give you something like:

[image]

Then you can modify the `x` and `y` values in your `.csv` file to place your turtles where you want them. Would that work?

Of course, you can add other columns in the `.csv` file (like color, size, shape, etc) that will help you identify turtles at a glance.