# Netlogo assign group of patches to own variable of a breed

Tags: netlogo

I'm very new to netlogo and am wondering how I can set a group of patches to be an own variable to a certain breed. For example, let's say I have:

```
breed [ buildings building ]
buildings-own [ my-patches ]
```

I want to be able to have a set of patches (let's say a rectangle, so constrained by some coordinates) that are assigned to each individual building's my-patches field. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow and Netlogo! Given your breed and `buildings-own` as above, you can simply use `set` to assign the `patch-set` that you want a building's `my-patches` variable to hold.

```
to setup
  ca
  ask patches with [ pxcor mod 10 = 0 and pycor mod 10 = 0 ] [
    sprout-buildings 1 [ 
      set shape "square"
      set heading 0
      set size 1.5
      set my-patches patches with [ 
        pxcor > [pxcor] of myself - 3 and
        pxcor < [pxcor] of myself + 3 and 
        pycor > [pycor] of myself - 3 and
        pycor < [pycor] of myself + 3
      ]
      ask my-patches [
        set pcolor [color] of myself - 2
      ]
    ]
  ]
  reset-ticks
end
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way I can assign a unique id to each of the buildings?

Comment: You're welcome! The buildings all have a unique `who` identifier (try `ask buildings [ show who ]`) that is assigned based on the order that they are created. However, if you want more precise control over xy locations and location-specific names, my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45361848/netlogo-set-specific-setxy-patern-with-set-number-of-turtles/45362094#45362094) might work for you. If you're trying to represent real-worlds buildings, you might want to get into the `GIS` extension down the line (but that's more complicated and uses shapefiles to assign names/values).

Answer (score 2):

First thing you need to know is that you can't have breeds of patches. While you don't say that's what you want, I just want to make sure you are aware of this.

Have a look at this code. It is a complete program that creates some turtles (called realtors) and assigns them each some patches. It then turns those patches the same colour as the realtor.

```
breed [realtors realtor]
realtors-own [my-patches]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-realtors 10
  [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set size 2
    set shape "circle"
    set my-patches n-of 5 patches in-radius 3
  ]
  ask realtors [ask my-patches [set pcolor [color] of myself ] ]
  reset-ticks
end
```

You can run it by creating a button for 'setup' or simply typing setup in the command centre.